# Вывод данных в файл без пробелов

Tags: c#, вывод

Как сделать вывод данных в файл без пробелов?

Данный метод сохраняет данные из `RichTextBox`

```
private void writeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog2.Filter = "Текстовый файл(*.txt)|*.txt|Все файлы(*.*)|*.*";
    if (saveFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamWriter streamwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(saveFileDialog2.FileName, true, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        streamwriter.Write(this.rx_textarea.Text);
        streamwriter.Close();
    }
}

private void update_rxtextarea_event(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        if (rx_textarea.Lines.Count() > 5000)
            rx_textarea.ResetText();
            rx_textarea.AppendText("" + data );
    }));
}
```

`data` это цифровые данные полученные из СОМ порта.

```
data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(dataRecevied);
```

Comment: `streamwriter.Write(this.rx_textarea.Text.Replace(" ", ""));` ?

Comment: так не получается

Comment: @Aforizm конкретнее